Is the set of primitive recursive reals recursively enumerable?
Let's define a primitive recursive real as a real which is the output of a primitive  recursive function (the function that computes its binary expansion for instance).
The set of primitive  recursive reals is not recursive because  of the Rice theorem.
Is it recursively enumerable?
Real numbers like $\pi= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k + 1}$ and $e=\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$ are primitive recursive reals as all outputs of real valued analytic functions (with primitive recursive real parameters) on primitive recursive real input.
To answer my questions somebody should answer first the question: are there recursive reals which are not primitive recursive?
If primitive  recursive reals are the same as recursive reals then their set is not a r.e. set, because if you list them recursively you can a build a recursive real on the diagonal which is not  in the list and this brings to a contradiction.
If primitive recursive reals are not the same as recursive reals one could still try to apply the same argument of the proof I mentioned by replacing recursive with primitive recursive, although if the number on the diagonal is not primitive recursive than the proof would fail.
If the set of recursive reals is Turing equivalent to the set of recursive sets then its Turing degree is $\emptyset'''$  (see Turing Computability, R. I. Soare)
If the set of primitive recursive reals is not r.e. and is not the same as the set of recursive reals, what is its Turing degree?

"all outputs of real valued analytic functions on primitive recursive real input" this is not correct. Every constant function is analytic, even a constant function whose constant value is not primitive recursive.

Yes, thank you for the correction, I will amend it.

What does it mean for a set of reals to be r.e. or not? (And yes, by direct diagonalization there are recursive reals which are not p.r.)

Is your question a hint or an objection?  Could you please elaborate on an example of a recursive non p.r. real?

Rice's Theorem is about sets of natural numbers, not sets of reals. As @NoahSchweber asked, what do you mean by an r.e. set of reals anyway? The standard definition of "recursively enumerable" applies to sets of natural numbers (or objects that can be coded as natural numbers).

@MitchellSpector is exactly right. As to my second comment, let $(p_i)_{i\in\omega}$ be some reasonable listing of the p.r. 0/1-valued functions and let $f(x)=1-p_x(x)$. This $f$ is recursive, but the infinite binary sequence it outputs is not that output by any p.r. function. Of course in order to argue that the corresponding real isn't p.r. we need to think a bit about reals with multiple binary expansions; there are several ways to handle this, though.

@NoahSchweber  how does the fact that to embed a set of recursive reals in to the naturals you can take the index of the recursive functions that generate each of them (either by choosing only one function for each real or by allowing repetitions) play in this question?
